# Ionic cordova-plugin-camera big issue on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, camera

in an ionic app, I want to take a picture and then show that in an image.

```
$scope.takePicture = function () {
                var options = {
                    quality: 50,

                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                    allowEdit: false,
                    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                    targetWidth: 640,
                    targetHeight: 640,
                    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                    saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
                    correctOrientation:true
                };

                $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {

                var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
                image.src = imageData;
})
}
```

On ios all is ok, and in my app I see the image in

On Android, I don't see anything! But the image is correctly saved, becouse I can send the image file in my server without problems.

I try to add:

```
<allow-navigation href="file:*"/>
```

in my config.xml, and I add:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; img-src 'self' data: file: *">
```

in my index.html, to consider safe the images under 'file:'

But, again, without results.

Any help????

Massimo

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid() && (imageData.indexOf("file://") === -1)) {
   image.src = "file://" + imageData
} else {
   image.src = imageData
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) 
{
   var data  = imageData;
   var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
   image.src = data.split('?')[0];
})
```